# convert listbox value to comma separated string with single quotes

Tags: sql, asp.net

i have a listbox with more than 100 items i want this 100 items to be comma separated with single quotes e.g: ''abc','def'' i want this to search in a select clause

```
 List<string> SelectedValue = new List<string>();
       foreach (ListItem lst in ListBox2.Items)
       {
           if (lst.Selected)
           {

               SelectedValue.Add(lst.Value);
           }
       }
string.Join(",",SelectedValue.Select(x=>string.Format("'{0}'",x)));
```

its giving me error 'the best overloaded method match for 'string.join has some invalid arguments, what an doing wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest a slightly different approach using a `StringBuilder` instead of putting the items into a `List` object? You are flatting these out to CSV anyways, so why not just build it that way like so..

```
var SB = new StringBuilder();
foreach (ListItem lst in ListBox2.Items)
   {
       if (lst.Selected)
       {
           SB.Append("'" + list.value + "',");
       }
   }
var FinalString = SB.ToString().Substring(0, (SB.Length - 1));
```

Comment: thanx.your code does what i exactly wanted. but why theres a problem in my code its achievable by that also

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the result of `SelectedValue.Select` to an array:

```
String result =  string.Join(",", SelectedValue.Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x)).ToArray());`
```

Comment: Please edit your answer add some explanation. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough (but can be hard to understand for other visitors), but Conde+explanation answers are always better

Answer (score 0):

You linq query returns a result of type `IEnumerable` you must convert it to a string array:

```
List<string> selectedValue = (from ListItem lst in ListBox1.Items 
                              where lst.Selected 
                              select lst.Value).ToList();
//convert to array using ToArray()
string[] arr = selectedValue.Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x)).ToArray();
string data = string.Join(",",arr);
```